# LESS: combine properties (rules) with same value

Tags: css, less

I am using LESS CSS preprocessor. For example if there are two (or more) rules with same value

```
.my-class {
    border-top: 2px solid @main-bg-color - #123456;
    border-bottom: 2px solid @main-bg-color - #123456;
}
```

can I combine those two into one somehow like this?

```
.my-class {
    border-top, border-bottom: 2px solid @main-bg-color - #123456;
}
```

**UPDATE**: You shouldn't be concentrated on the props (`border`) I wrote just as example. I'd like to know if there's any way to combine any multiple props with same value. If there is no way to do so, please say it explicitly.

Comment: non-less, but also non-repetitive, you could do `border: solid @main-bg-color; border-width: 2px 0;`

Comment: No, you shouldn't combine the two.  It wouldn't be ideal for readability and maintainability.  Just keep it the way you had it.

Comment: What about use mixins ?

Comment: Why not just  [variables](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.my-class%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%5Ct%40x%3A%202px%20solid%20%40foo%20-%20%23123456%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20border-top%3A%20%40x%3B%20%20border-bottom%3A%20%40x%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%40foo%3A%20white%3B%22%7D)? And to answer *If there is no way to do so, please say it explicitly.* - Then *No*, there's no anything similar to your example (it's just too rare and specific case to have a dedicated syntax).

Comment: @seven-phases-max `width: @foo; height: @foo;` seems quite a common case to me

Comment: `width: @foo; height: @foo;` - in that case they use `.square` mixin. So you're basically trying to invent some special language construction where more common and more generic patterns exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @seven-phases-max [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415907/less-combine-properties-rules-with-same-value#comment75853960_44415907), there is no way to combine several props with same value in LESS. Use [variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature) or [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use something like:

```
.my-class {
    border:  2px solid @main-bg-color - #123456;
    border-width: 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really relate to the problem. I upgraded the question to make it clearer.